Why did the High German Consonant Shift change the /th/ in the 3rd person singular present to /t/ instead of to /d/?
English 'th' corresponds to German 'd', as can be seen from words such as "three"-"drei", "thick"-"dick", "thin"-"dünn", "this"-"das", "that"-"dass", "there"-"da", "bath"-"Bad", "thirst"-"Durst", "thank"-"danken", and so on.
However, in Proto-Germanic, the present singular 3rd person ending was "-th", yet the German third-person singular present ending is -t, rather than -d. Why?

Hi FlatAssembler! You might be interested in reading this: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/what-is-the-problem-with-why-questions-and-how-to-deal-with-them

"why?"-questions are very hard to answer when you're not a contemporary speaker of proto-germanic during the  change....

@JonathanScholbach Well, my question is fairly similar to my previous two questions, both of which were relatively well-received.

Corollary to my first question here, it seems that I perceive dufte as /duf.de/ "good" but Duft /duft/ "fragrance". This is conducive to @Janka's answer about Auslautverhärtung. The most striking case is Stadt "city" as opposed to -statt "stead", and as far as final *th is concerned Stab "staff". Deriving from stabulum is irrelevant because -()ulum ultimately goes back to *trom, **dhlom-, e.g. girth, girdle, German Gurt, Gürtel. As you can see, and more examples corroborate, this goes all the way back and forth to PIE. Safe to say it's poorly understood. Take care, *mach'

German das is primarily English that, not this, (subject to exceptions in idiomatic usage).


yet the German third-person singular present ending is -t, rather than -d. Why?

There you have your answer. It's an ending, and because of Auslautverhärtung the common way to treat an ending -d is to speak it as -t anyways. It makes little sense to change the writing to -d but then speak it as before.

For example the word "Zwang" was written "zwanc" in Middle High German because they wrote phonetically back then. And because the spoke it with a "k" (not a "g") at the end they also wrote it that way.

Yeah, but nowadays -ng is a consonant on its own [ŋ] that isn't subject to Auslautverhärtung. If you want the latter, you have to write -nk as in Fink for example. That's -[ŋk].
